# Возможно ли скомпилировать java файл игнорируя импорты?

Tags: java, javac

Решил заняться моддингом андроид приложений, скачал нужный апк, всё сделал, декомпилировал нужный мне файл *.class в *.java и внёс нужные изменения. Так вот, возможно ли скомпилировать этот файл обратно в class не декомпилируя весь проект? (Если я вдруг иду не в том направлении в моддинге, то скажите, а то я в этом совсем новичок)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главное чтобы код был без ошибок!
Только если будешь импортировать классы из других файлов, необходимо их тоже добавить.

Comment: в этом и беда, не хочу весь проект перелопачивать.. ну ладно, спасибо вам)

Answer (score 0):

Если нет ошибок в коде, то конечно, можно скомпилировать любой java файл, но если, к примеру, в вашем файле используется импорт классов из других файлов (наследование), то без сомнений, будут ошибки